# How to politely tell someone I'd rather speak English with him than German

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

I am waiting a call from a German native speaker and I'd like to tell him, that even though I can speak German relatively okay, I'd rather speak English as it's easier.

> Ich bevorzuge Englisch sprechen. Obwohl ich gute Deutsch spreche.

I don't know why but it feels more like it should be `spricht` rather than `spreche` but I am not sure.

Two questions please:

- Is it grammatically correct ?
- Is it polite ? in the sense I am not being rude like (I don't want to talk German only English!) it would feel to me a bit aggressive.

Comment: Actually telling this in broken German might bring the point over better ;-)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I like to be accurate :)

Comment: Haha I just now understood what you meant ;)

Comment: (not actually answering the question, but I thought it relevant) In my experience if you start the conversation in English, your counterpart is unlikely to switch to German in Germany or Austria. Avoids the whole kerfuffle, although nobody would be offended by your sentence.

Comment: What I miss in the answers, but does not justify an own answer: The translation of "I can speak German relatively ok" to "Obwohl ich gute Deutsch spreche" does not fit. "relatively ok" is "einigermaßen" or "gebrochen", but not "gut" (good). It also fits with the given example sentence, it is understandable, but not good German.

Comment: @ThorstenS. Ich habe Deutsch an der Universität gelernt, und A22 kurs gemacht hat. Deshalb glaube ich mein Deutsch is nur Okay. Gut is nicht super aber nur Okay ? :D I guess more grammatical mistakes here but I hope you understand what I meant.
Relatively Okay in my lexicon is good. I guess its a perspective.

Comment: @TonyTannous Your German is so far clearly and intelligible and you will be normally understood (and nobody is bothered), but some parts of it contains still too much foreign grammar. It is not a problem because Germans autocorrect it in their head, but "good" from a German perspective is the second highest grade and some Germans are quite demanding :o)

Comment: @ThorstenS. thanks I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @TonyTannous I suggest [this translated article](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38177/how-do-you-know-if-americans-genuinely-literally-mean-what-they-say/38192#38192). The reason is that when both Germans and Americans meet, they often *think* they are very similar, but in fact they have a huge potential for misunderstandings.

Comment: @ThorstenS. I will read this though I am not American/native English speaker. Thanks again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your German quote is not quite accurate, it should look this way:

> Ich bevorzuge es, Englisch zu sprechen. Obwohl ich gut Deutsch
>   spreche.

But this doesn't fit very well, it's rather impolite. I would propose:

> [Ich kann zwar einigermaßen gut Deutsch, aber] würde es Ihnen etwas ausmachen, wenn ich Englisch rede?

or

> [Ich kann zwar einigermaßen gut Deutsch, aber] hätten Sie etwas dagegen, wenn ich Englisch spreche?

Comment: *[...] wenn ich Englisch spreche?* sounds a little odd, unless you expect the conversation to be bilingual - you speaking English, the other speaking German. I'd put it as *[...] wenn wir Englisch sprechen?*

Comment: @Raketenolli: _ich_ is more polite because the German isn't asked to speak English. Many Germans can understand English quite well, but have a problem in talking, would consider it unreasonable _(Zumutung)_.

Answer (score 5):

I'd rather say

> Ich bevorzuge Englisch *zu* sprechen, obwohl ich *gut* Deutsch spreche.

This seems to be polite as a statement, however usually questions give the impression to be even more kind. One suggestion:

> Würde es Sie stören, das Gespräch auf Englisch zu führen?

Usually you can expect a "Nein" as an answer and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it:

> Können wir liebe Englisch sprechen, bitte?  Ist leichter für mich.

That might have some mistakes, but as Paulo pointed out, that probably acts in my favor.  The other thing that helps is to say the above a bit on the slow, tentative side.  The other person will want the conversation to go quicker and if s/he is comfortable in English, will immediately switch.